# WinHTTP background thread count

Tags: c++, multithreading, http, asynchronous, winhttp

I'm using WinHTTP in order to create client http request.
although it's working good most of the time, I have 
a bit of confusion regarding the thread pool Windows
opens for async winhttp connections.

As written in MSDN about `WinHttpSetOption` function:

> WINHTTP_OPTION_WORKER_THREAD_COUNT
>
> ```
> Sets an unsigned long integer value that specifies the number of worker threads the thread pool should use for asynchronous
> ```
>
> completions. The default value of this option is zero, which specifies
>   that the number of worker threads is equal to the number of CPUs on
>   the system. This option can only be set on a NULL  HINTERNET handle
>   before an asynchronous operation has occurred. This option can only be
>   set once.
>
> ```
> Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7:  This flag is obsolete.
> ```

So, let's say I want to fire 100 asynchronous request -
In my Visual Studio debugging tools I can clearly see that
my app is opening 100 background threads (!).
this is not scalable at all. since I target windows 7/Windows servers above 2008 and above,
I can't call `WinHttpSetOption` with `WINHTTP_OPTION_WORKER_THREAD_COUNT` option.

So my question is - is there any workaround this? 
I would like to keep the thread count as low as possible
while being able to fire many http requests asynchronously.